# Statically linking a binary that uses regex_macros

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I just realised that Rust binaries created via Cargo are dynamically linked when I use the `regex_macros` crate. This is a bit problematic as the created binary will cease to work when I update to a newer version of `regex_macros`.

Is there a way around that?

Here's a minimal example:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#[plugin]
extern crate regex_macros;


fn main() {}
```

Compiling this and looking at what is linked reveals this:

```
uh@macaron:~/linking-test (master)$ otool -L target/linking-test
target/linking-test:
    /Users/uh/linking-test/target/deps/libregex_macros-bdbdbfedad0748ac.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libflate-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libgetopts-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_back-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libsyntax-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libfmt_macros-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libarena-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libterm-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libgraphviz-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librbml-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libserialize-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblog-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_llvm-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-4e7c5e5c.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

As you can see, the first linked dylib has an absolute path into the directory where the project lives and even doing a `cargo clean` will probably break the executable.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.

Comment: Can you show a minimally reproducible example with enough information for someone else to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try to see if I can come up with a minimal example. I noticed it when compiling my project (https://github.com/ujh/iomrascalai), but that one is already quite big and of course isn't suitable for debugging.

Comment: Try using `#[plugin] #[no_link] extern crate regex_macros;`.

Comment: Yes, it was right there in the documentation ... Thank you! :)

Comment: does this help at all? From the text it seems that you could force all dependencies to be linked in your preference. http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#building-dynamic-or-static-libraries

Answer (score 3):

They tiny detail that is missing here is `#[no_link]` as mentioned in a comment by [BurntSushi5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619216/burntsushi5). So changing the code to:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#[plugin] #[no_link] extern crate regex_macros;


fn main() {}
```

Will link the regex_macros crate statically.

Comment: "link the regex_macros crate statically" - Shouldn't an attribute called `#[no_link]` not link it at all?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken that binaries are dynamically linked (at least not by default).

I just created a brand new binary project with Cargo (`cargo new --bin foo`), added the [regex crate](https://crates.io/crates/regex) and used it in the source. I compiled the binary, I then used `otool` to list the dynamic libraries (I'm on OS X):

```
$ otool -L target/statik
target/statik:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

This seems to indicate that the only dynamic linking is to core system libraries (on Linux, I believe it is glibc).

Comment: When I do it with my project (https://github.com/ujh/iomrascalai) I get a lot of output where you only get that one line. I will try to come up with a minimal example ...